# How do I evaluate arbitrary expressions in a spacebars argument?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'd like say something like `{{#if tiny || huge}}`, but it looks like spacebars only takes a truthy function.  What's the best solution?

I thought I'd write another helper, but how do I call one helper from another helper's code?  E.g.

```
Template.foo.helpers({ tiny: function() { return this < 10 },
                       huge: function() { return this > 1000 },
                       tinyOrHuge: function() { return tiny() || huge() } // bzzt!
})
```

I don't want to rewrite `tinyOrHuge` by duplicating `tiny` and `huge`.  That's not very DRY.

Is there a programmatic way to access the helper functions by name?  It would be nice if `helpers` returned the helper if you passed in the name.  E.g. I could call `Template.foo.helpers('tiny')()`.  But I've looked at these Blaze.Template objects and don't see a way to get the functions back without accessing private vars, e.g. `Template.foo.__helpers.get('tiny')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of reusing your helper functions while keeping the necessary context:

```js
var tiny = function() {
  return this < 10;
};

var huge = function() {
  return this > 1000;
};

Template.foo.helpers({
  tiny: tiny,

  huge: huge,

  tinyOrHuge: function() {
    return tiny.call(this) || huge.call(this);
  }
});
```